# Convert query PIVOT from Oracle to SQL Server error

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, pivot

Currently I am converting the an Oracle trigger to SQL Server, but I run into a problem.

My query in Oracle is like this

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER_ID, NVL(MATRIX1,0) MATRIX1, NVL(MATRIX2,0) MATRIX2
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         CUSTOMER_ID, SCORE 
     FROM STABLE) A
PIVOT (SUM(1) AS SCORE_MATRIX FOR (SCORE) IN (
                                              1 AS IND_1, 2 AS IND_2));
```

My T-SQL query in SQL Server looks like this

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER_ID, ISNULL(MATRIX1,0) AS MATRIX1, ISNULL(MATRIX2,0) AS MATRIX2
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         CUSTOMER_ID, SCORE 
     FROM STABLE) A
PIVOT (SUM(1) AS SCORE_MATRIX FOR (SCORE) IN (
                                              1 AS IND_1, 2 AS IND_2)) PVT;
```

However I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
>   Incorrect syntax near '1'.

I could not figure out why for this error, so could anyone help identify? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `count(*)` in both cases.

Comment: Huh? Are you saying the Oracle query works? Who are MATRIX1 and MATRIX2 which appear within NVL in the outer SELECT?

Comment: Your source table is not returning two columns you call later. Also, the error code is incorrect. You are calling the values to be pivoted wrong. Read [SQLAuthority - Pivot](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the `SUM(1)`. 
Since 1 is not a column in the source query A.

Also, on sql-server those alias names within the PIVOT declaration aren't allowed like on Oracle.

So with a few fixes the PIVOT will work on sql-server.

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER_ID, ISNULL([1],0) AS MATRIX1, ISNULL([2],0) AS MATRIX2
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID, SCORE FROM STABLE) AS A
PIVOT (
    COUNT(SCORE) FOR SCORE IN ([1], [2])
) AS PVT;
```

#### Notes:

SUM(1) was replaced by COUNT(SCORE).
And that COUNT(SCORE) will give either 1 or NULL in that PIVOT for SCORE.
So this will also result in a matrix filled with 0 a 1.

Comment: You moved the PIVOT inside the subquery? Why? Just to make it work? The original post had the PIVOT in the outer query (which made no sense), but the OP claimed (or maybe he didn't?) that the query was OK in Oracle.